# Style / remove axis overlap indicator in lightningChart js

Tags: charts, lightningchart

I would like to style axes in LightningChartJs and are not able to remove the little lines on axis overlap and the end of axis (Please see image below).

To set thickness of axis has no effect on the indicators:

```
const axisYStyles = axisYColors.map((color) => new SolidFill({ color }));
const axisYStrokeStyles = axisYStyles.map((fillStyle) => new SolidLine({ fillStyle, thickness: 1 }));
    
const axisX = this.chart.getDefaultAxisX()
                            .setStrokeStyle(axisYStrokeStyles[0]);
```

Would be nice if someone can help and explain how to remove or style this items. Thx in advance.

[image: lightningChartJs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The little lines at the ends of the axis line are called "nibs". You can style and hide the nibs with [`Axis.setNibStyle()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/axis.html#setnibstyle).

[`emptyLine`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/globals.html#emptyline) can be used to completely remove the axis and nib lines.

```js
// Axis styling
chart.getDefaultAxisX()
    // Hide the main axis line
    .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
    // Hide the Nib at the ends of the axis
    .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
```

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
    lightningChart,
    emptyLine
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart()
    .ChartXY()

// Axis styling
chart.getDefaultAxisX()
    // Hide the main axis line
    .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
    // Hide the Nib at the ends of the axis
    .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
chart.getDefaultAxisY()
    // Hide the main axis line
    .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
    // Hide the Nib at the ends of the axis
    .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow! That was easy. :D Thank you very much.